# Ordinary Differential Equation with trigs!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help and alternative ways of solving this problem: 
$$ y'(x^2 + 1) - 2xy = (x^2 + 1)\arctan x $$
Thank you for all kind of help and hints :)

Comment: Try dividing through by $x^2+x$ and using a linear differential equations solution method.  Are you sure that shouldn't be $x^2+1$?

Comment: Yes, and also y(1) = 2

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(x^2+1\right)y' -2xy = \left(x^2+1\right)\arctan x 
$$

$$
y' -\frac{2x}{x^2+1}y = \arctan x 
$$

$$
\frac{g'}{g} = \frac{2x}{x^2+1} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln g(x)
$$
thus
$$
y\mathrm{e}^{-\ln g} = \frac{y}{g} = \int \frac{1}{g}\arctan x dx = \int \frac{1}{x^2+1}\arctan x dx 
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x = \frac{1}{x^2+1}
$$

therefore

$$
\frac{y}{x^2+1} = \int \left(\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x\right)\arctan x dx = \int \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\arctan^2 x}{2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(x) +C.
$$

Comment: I was working with the OP on his problem.  You have done his work for him.  How does this help?

Comment: Thank you @Chinny84, 
Mr.Sundheim I am still listening :)

Comment: @sundheim Yes, and I clearly see that your doing a fine job. But though admirable a task to walk a person through a problem (and in fact I firmly believe that you should do so still) it is hard to regulate such things other than I decide to say "person x is working through this problem with me". You can still work through the answer, and next time I will keep that in mind before posting on straight forward solutions :) (though in my defence the first equation from the OP was a tad more interesting which I was working on ;)) keep up the good work!

Comment: Also OP when you do accept, accept the answer of the fine fellow that has worked through the problem with you :).

Answer (score 1):

Then divide through by $x^2+1$ and integrate $m=e^{\int{\frac{-2x}{x^2+1}}}$ to get the integrating factor.

Comment: I've done that and got :
(y(-x^2 -1) )' = arctan x * (-x^2-1) 
When I integrate the right side I get some problem :/

Comment: By "divide through" I mean divide each term by $x^2+1$ to arrive at $y'-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}y=\arctan{x}$. Did you do that?

Comment: This method of solution is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients

Comment: Yes, 
as you got, I get : 
$$ y´- 2xy/(x^2 +1) = arctan x $$
Which gives: 
$$ y*(-x^2 -1) = (arctan x * (-x^2-1) )dx $$
It's the last part with the integration of $$ arctan x * (-x^2 -1) dx $$ which gives me a hard time :/

Comment: At the web page link I gave you, it gives the solution to the equation as a formula $y=...$. Do you see it?

Comment: By the way, your statement above following "Which gives" cannot be correct, there is a $dx$ on the right side but no differential on the left.  I don't see how you got the left side.

Comment: Yes, I do see it..

Comment: If I get one step back : 
$$ y´−2xy/(x2+1)=arctanx $$
$$ (y(x)(-x^2-1))' = (arctan x * (-x^2-1) )$$
so now we have :
$$ y∗(−x2−1)=(arctanx∗(−x2−1))dx $$

Comment: Good, the $m$ I mentioned above is what they are calling $e^{a(x)}$

Comment: Yes I know and e^(ln(x^2+1)) = (x^2 + 1) 
thats why you don't see my e^(a(x))

Comment: See the complete solution given above by Chinny84.  You were integrating $a(x)$ incorrectly. $m=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ not ${-x^2-1}$ :) Could you up-vote my answer? Thanks

Comment: But wait: Integrating 2x/ (x^2 +1), isnt it ln (x^2 +1 ) ???

Comment: There is a minus sign, so it ends up being $\ln{(x^2+1)^{-1}}$

Comment: Ooohh CRAP! :( 4 hours for a small error ! 
Many thanks :)

Comment: There are double arrows next to the (rather short) answer I gave above.  Could you push the up arrow?

Comment: I cant my reputation is too low :( 
But I will when I can !